# SQL Bigquery - Get first value for change in values in a column values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have rows as below in a BigQuery table, sorted based on the `date` column asc, whenever `type=0`, the previous non-zero value from `type` should be taken and applied to the current argument.

| Row | date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/12/17 | 4 |
| 2 | 02/12/17 | 0 |
| 3 | 03/12/17 | 4 |
| 4 | 04/12/17 | 0 |
| 5 | 05/12/17 | 0 |
| 6 | 06/12/17 | 0 |
| 7 | 07/12/17 | 0 |
| 8 | 08/12/17 | 4 |
| 9 | 09/12/17 | 5 |
| 10 | 10/12/17 | 6 |
| 11 | 11/12/17 | 0 |
| 12 | 12/12/17 | 5 |
| 13 | 13/12/17 | 0 |
| 14 | 14/12/17 | 0 |
| 15 | 15/12/17 | 5 |

The expected output is:

| Row | date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/12/17 | 4 |
| 2 | 02/12/17 | 4 |
| 3 | 03/12/17 | 4 |
| 4 | 04/12/17 | 4 |
| 5 | 05/12/17 | 4 |
| 6 | 06/12/17 | 4 |
| 7 | 07/12/17 | 4 |
| 8 | 08/12/17 | 4 |
| 9 | 09/12/17 | 5 |
| 10 | 10/12/17 | 6 |
| 11 | 11/12/17 | 6 |
| 12 | 12/12/17 | 5 |
| 13 | 13/12/17 | 5 |
| 14 | 14/12/17 | 5 |
| 15 | 15/12/17 | 5 |

Can someone assist me on this to update the table.

Comment: Please replace images with formatted tables. See [why should I not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining the previous values is done by window functions.

```sql
Select *,
last_value(if(type=0,null,type) ignore nulls) over fill_na

from yourtable
window fill_na as (order by date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel, it helped me to achieve what I want and this is a new learning for me :)